# How to compare the value from the dictionary with records in the database?

Tags: python, dictionary, rules

I have a dictionary with rules like this:

```
dict_items([(8, 'curtosis > -5.274 V entropy > -5.414 V skewness > 4.875 V variance = [[1.2572]]'), (9, 'curtosis > 8.682 V entropy > -4.492 V  skewness > 4.875 V variance = [[0.89512]]')])
```

where V = or

I use a database [banknote](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00267/)

```
   variance  skewness  curtosis  entropy  class
0   3.62160    8.6661   -2.8073 -0.44699      0
1   4.54590    8.1674   -2.4586 -1.46210      0
2   3.86600   -2.6383    1.9242  0.10645      0
3   3.45660    9.5228   -4.0112 -3.59440      0
4   0.32924   -4.4552    4.5718 -0.98880      0
(1372, 5)
```

I need to compare the values from the dictionary with every records in the database. 
Example:

Rule 8:

```
if -2.8073 > -5.274 or -0.44699 > -5.414 or 8.6661 > 4.875 or 3.62160 = 1.2572
```

Then I create a table with values 1 or 0. If the rule is true, type 1 otherwise 0. Something like that:

```
    Rule 8  Rule 9  class
0     1      1        0
1     1      0        0
2     1      0        0
3     1      1        0 
4     1      0        0
```

I have no idea how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary, `diction`, that maps the values that makeup rules. Then create columns 'Rule-8' & 'Rule-9' based on your conditions

```
diction={'Rule-8':[-5.274,-5.414,4.875,1.2572],'Rule-9':[8.682,-4.492, 4.875 ,0.89512]}

df['Rule-8']= ((df['variance']>diction['Rule-8'][0]) & (df['skewness']>diction['Rule-8'][1]) & (df['curtosis']>diction['Rule-8'][2]) & (df['entropy']>diction['Rule-8'][3]))
df['Rule-9']= ((df['variance']>diction['Rule-9'][0]) & (df['skewness']>diction['Rule-9'][1]) & (df['curtosis']>diction['Rule-9'][2]) & (df['entropy']>diction['Rule-9'][3])) 

df['Rule-8']=df['Rule-8'].astype(int)# converts False to 0's and True to 1's
df['Rule-9']=df['Rule-9'].astype(int)# converts False to 0's and True to 1's
```